# Spring XML parse exception

Tags: java, xml, spring, xsd, xml-parsing

Im getting this exception when trying to start a Spring web application on a machine that has no internet access.

```
.... more duplicate definition errors
2015-11-11 00:58:19,284 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-1) http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd<Line 1048, Column 39>: XML-24509: (Error) Duplicated definition for: 'propertyType'
2015-11-11 00:58:19,284 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-1) http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd<Line 1092, Column 41>: XML-24509: (Error) Duplicated definition for: 'collectionType'
2015-11-11 00:58:19,284 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-1) http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd<Line 1104, Column 40>: XML-24509: (Error) Duplicated definition for: 'listOrSetType'
2015-11-11 00:58:19,284 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-1) http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd<Line 1113, Column 34>: XML-24509: (Error) Duplicated definition for: 'mapType'
2015-11-11 00:58:19,284 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-1) http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd<Line 1135, Column 36>: XML-24509: (Error) Duplicated definition for: 'entryType'
2015-11-11 00:58:19,284 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-1) http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd<Line 1182, Column 36>: XML-24509: (Error) Duplicated definition for: 'propsType'
2015-11-11 00:58:19,285 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-1) http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd<Line 1195, Column 45>: XML-24509: (Error) Duplicated definition for: 'defaultable-boolean'
2015-11-11 00:58:19,286 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.PluggableSchemaResolver] (MSC  service thread 1-1) Found XML schema [http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd] in  classpath: org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.2.xsd
2015-11-11 00:58:19,288 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.PluggableSchemaResolver] (MSC service thread 1-1) Found XML schema [http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd] in classpath: org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
2015-11-11 00:58:19,289 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.PluggableSchemaResolver] (MSC service thread 1-1) Found XML schema [http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-3.2.xsd] in classpath: org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.2.xsd
2015-11-11 00:58:19,291 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.PluggableSchemaResolver] (MSC service thread 1-1) Found XML schema [http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd] in classpath: org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
2015-11-11 00:58:19,293 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.PluggableSchemaResolver] (MSC service thread 1-1) Found XML schema [http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd] in classpath: org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
2015-11-11 00:58:19,293 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.PluggableSchemaResolver] (MSC service thread 1-1) Found XML schema [http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-3.2.xsd] in classpath: org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.2.xsd
2015-11-11 00:42:03,990 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (MSC service thread 1-2) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 10 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/service-servlet.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 10; columnNumber: 113; <Line 10, Column 113>: XML-24500: (Error) Can not build schema 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans' located at 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd'
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
```

The application context is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop      http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd">
```

All Spring dependencies in the pom are version 3.2.0.RELEASE, as well. I have checked that all XSD's are available on the class path, of specified versions, and the spring.handlers and spring.schemas seem correct and point to right/existing handlers and schemas.

What else could be the problem?

EDIT: there are other applications in the same container. Could that have something to do with this problem?

The service-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd">

<!-- <import resource="applicationContext.xml" /> -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.my.package" />
<mvc:annotation-driven
    content-negotiation-manager="contentNegotiationManager" />
<bean id="contentNegotiationManager"
    class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="favorPathExtension" value="false" />
</bean>
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jsonConverter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jsonConverter"
    class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json"></property>
</bean>
```

Comment: I'll be honest, generally when I have errors like these, I do the very high tech solution of deleting a chunk of xml, and asking "now does it work?" over and over until i find which line is causing the problem

Comment: Please paste the contents of the service-servlet.xml file.

Comment: Could you please remove everything but beans from your schemaLocation i.e. **xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd"** and give it a try.  I'm curious to see if you get the same error.

Comment: @Kabir - I removed everything down to <beans xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd"> and it still wasnt working. When I changed XSD and dependency versions to 4.2 with just one line in servlet.xml and context.xml server started. Really not sure what to make of it.

Comment: Continued playing with this issue in spare time -- it appears that it only happens if project as packaged as a war and deployed to any web container, and only then it is is unable to initialize. If it is packaged as a jar, and controller method can be invoked from main and works more or less correctly. Any thoughts?